# Can a massless electric charge particle exist in a de Sitter universe?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, charge, qft-in-curved-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

Because of the cosmological constant, our universe may reach a de Sitter universe in the far future. If we suppose this, the most basic group of particle physics will be the Sitter, rather than Poincaré. Mass is a Casimir operator of the Poincaré group, but not of the de Sitter group. Does this mean that a massless electric charge particle can be stable in a de Sitter universe?